# check if prop of selected dropdown is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm having trouble to check if the selected option of a dropdown is disabled.

The user has the possibility to choose a option and then select a time range, after the time selection, all the options not available in this range will be set to disabled. If the previous selected value was also disabled there must be an alert.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
if($('#dropdown').val().prop('disabled',true)){
alert('not possible'); 
}
```

Comment: Can you select a disabled option in a `select` box?

Comment: yes because the option will only be disabled after the user enters a date range. The first Answer worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `:selected` option then check its `prop()`

```
if($('#dropdown option:selected').prop('disabled') == true){
    //Selected option is disabled
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
if($('#dropdown').find(':selected').prop('disabled')){
  alert('not possible'); 
}
```

```js
$('input').change(function(){
  if($(this).val()>50){
    $('select option:first-child').prop('disabled',true);
  }
  if($('select').find(':selected').prop('disabled')){
      alert('not possible'); 
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="range"/>
```

Comment: @nogato,don't forget to vote or accept an asnwer ! Please take a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work , in order to help other people.

Comment: Yes i won't. I cant vote because i lack reputation and there is a wait time until i can accept an answer :-)

Comment: @nogato, I updated my answer with an example. When you slide more 50 then option selected will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check the count of selected and disabled option. Use [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) and [`:disabled`](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) pseudo-class selectors for selecting the option.

```
if($('#dropdown option:selected:disabled').length){
   alert('not possible'); 
}
```